# Cannot Resolve R.menu and other R. stuff in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have been practicing in Android Studio as per the android app development free course in UDACITY. And wherever there is a R.menu or R. stuff it cannot be resolved

```
package com.example.android.courtcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Displays the given score for Team A.
 */
public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}
}
```

Plz help how to solve this Issue.

Comment: Clean and rebuild. This is a common issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 7):

1. Clean and rebuild your project by going to Build>Clean Project.
2. Go to File>Invalidate Caches/Restart.
3. Make sure you built your project, and make sure there aren't any errors (red lines) in the <kbd>res</kbd> directory.

Answer (score 1):

remove `import android.R;` clean and rebuild it.
if it still doesn't work try this

```
import com.example.android.courtcounter.R;
```

Check you AndroidManifest.xml, check the package name there.
use that as import .R; in code.

Comment: Removing `import android.R` will actually CAUSE the error. -1

Comment: he has to import his R file path not android.R
that why I asked to check with
import com.example.android.courtcounter.R;

Comment: He doesn't even have to import that. Android Studio does everything for him. I don't have any import for `R`, and AS does it for me. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: that's what i told first remove import android.R; and clean and rebuild it. Please read it fully

Comment: Ah, oops. Sorry. I'll see if I can remove the downvote

Comment: Still not working. After even cleaning and then rebuilding it is showing error                  'C:\Users\SAMADDAR\Desktop\Programming\Java\BlueJ\AndroidStudioProjects\CourtCounter\app\src\main\java\com\example\android\courtcounter\MainActivity.java
Error:(21, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable menu
Error:(33, 23) error: cannot find symbol variable action_settings
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED'

Comment: And then when i include that import.com.example.android.courtcounter.R; It is saying unused import statement

Comment: And in the R.layout.activity_main it is not causing any error. But in R.menu.menu_main and R.id.action_settings it is not able to resolve  **menu** and **action_settings**

Comment: How is your folder structure? can you share your menu xml file

Comment: also check your menu.xml in /res/menu/ folder